# How to Install Android Apps to the SD Card by Default

Tags: android, adb

I am following this tutorial for moving apps to sd card.

[How to Install Android Apps to the SD Card by Default](http://www.addictiveblogs.com/how-to-move-all-android-apps-to-sd-card-without-rooting-device/)

But My Default Location is not changing. And My Phone Memory is full and unable to install new apps.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question. Try http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay. Posted on android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After Android Tools Update command `adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2` has been changed to `adb shell pm set-install-location 2`  (note the command is case sensitive)

Updated Tutorial can be founded [here](http://www.addictiveblogs.com/how-to-move-all-android-apps-to-sd-card-without-rooting-device/).

Answer (score 5):

**android:installLocation="preferExternal"**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fpm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
  android:installLocation="preferExternal"
     >
```

[Refrence](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)